# Oscilloscope and mains voltage

Tags: oscilloscope

In the country were I live the mains electricity voltage is 230Vac. When I measure the mains voltage using an Uni-t UT52 multimeter, the multimeter measures about 247Vac.
It is safe to power the oscilloscope (model GDS 1052 U) at this voltage (247Vac)?
In the manual it is wrote that it can be powered at up to maximum 240Vac. Also in the manual it says "the power supply voltage should not fluctuate more than 10%".

It is safe to use the scope at 247Vac without any damage?
The oscilloscope could be damaged in time (after a few years or months of use) because of the high mains voltage?

Comment: Most likley yes. Is your scope marked 220-240 Vac or 230 Vac?

Comment: 10% over 240V is 264V, so 247V is well within spec.

Comment: In the manual of the scope it says: AC input voltage: 100-240Vac, 47-63Hz.

Comment: Then it's designed and tested for 264 Vac as per international standards. No problems.

Comment: *the multimeter measures about 247Vac.* Since you're using a meter that's not a **true RMS** meter, you have to take that 247V AC with a pinch of salt, the true RMS value of the voltage is likely to be **smaller**. The 240 V AC  rating on the scope **is** RMS because mains voltage is specified with the RMS value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I can use safely my scope at 247Vac ? @Bimpelrekkie

Comment: The RMS voltage is not bigger than the voltage measured by the multimeter ? @Bimpelrekkie

Comment: All I'm saying is that you cannot rely on the value that this multimeter will give you. Also I agree with what everyone else here says: it is safe to use the oscilloscope. Many devices have a 100 - 240 VAC rating and that means they can be used **worldwide**. The 240 AC refers to the **nominal mains AC voltage** which is 240 V in your case. It can be a bit lower or higher but equipment is designed to handle that. If not a lot of devices would be damaged each day as mains AC can vary **a lot**.

Comment: That multimeter is very susceptible. Even if the value multimeter reads is within the spec of an oscilloscope. So you don't need to worry about it. As other's calculation, you can use it without any doubts. If possible, use a better multimeter to confirm it.

Comment: All comments about the reliability of the multimeter and if it's really a true RMS meter are a bit over the top IMHO. Mains voltage is very close to sinusoidal so the meter needn't be a true RMS meter.

Answer (score 3):

That should be absolutely fine to use. Most of the time, a cheap digital multimeter will never give you great readings on AC voltage, but as the scope says it can fluctuate up to 10%, then you really shouldn't worry, it will be able to handle AC voltage up to 264V.